# Grails 4 not connecting to all datasources

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I'm in the midst of upgrading our Grails 2.5 app to Grails 4.0.3.  Having trouble getting the datasources to connect to the database.  We have multiple datasources defined, and I've kind of copied the config from the GORM documetation.  My application.yml file currently looks like

```
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: secret
    password: secret
    dbCreate: none
    url: local url here
    properties:
        jmxEnabled: true
        initialSize: 5
        maxActive: 50
        minIdle: 5
        maxIdle: 25
        maxWait: 10000
        maxAge: 600000
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
        validationQuery: SELECT 1
        validationQueryTimeout: 3
        validationInterval: 15000
        testOnBorrow: true
        testWhileIdle: true
        testOnReturn: false
        jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
        defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED

dataSources:
    foo:
        url: foo url
    bar:
        url: bar url
    baz:
        url: baz url
```

When I try to start the app, I see the connections being made to the default datasource and my foo datasource, but not anything after foo.  I am expecting to see connections to bar and baz.

Is there something I should be doing differently here, or something else to look at that could be causing this?

## Edit

I've tried changing the order of my dataSources block, and it always connects to the first datasource listed in that block.

Only difference between all of my datasources is the url.

## Edit 2

I was able to create a new app from scratch and copy the data sources into the application.yml and have that work.

## Edit 3

I've added into my new test app our plugin that defines all of our domain classes.  I am now seeing the same behavior  in this test app.  Any idea what could cause this from the domain classes?

## Edit 4 (Solution)

I started by copying my plugin's code into a new grails-app.  And then deleted domain classes until i found the culprit, a unique constraint on one of the classes was not working!  It's a weird case with an inheritance hierarchy, If I get a chance, I'll write up a simple demo to see if I can recreate the issue.  I changed the unique constraint and was able to start the app.

Comment: Assuming that all 4 data sources (`dataSource`, `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`) all share all of the same settings except for the url, what you have there looks right.  It is interesting that `foo` works.  It would be interesting to know if you change the order in the config file if that changes anything and also if you remove `foo` does one of the others take over as working?

Comment: Another piece of info that would be good to know is if all for of those urls share a driver class.

Comment: Yes, they are all MySQL datasources.  And yes, I've tried changing the order of the datasources, its always the first one that connects.

Comment: I don't understand how that could be, but I believe you.  If you file an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues with a sample app that demonstrates the issue, we can investigate.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Just tried an all new Grails 4.0.3 app from scratch and pasted in my datasources.  Thtatworks and i can see all the connection at the database level.  Must have something left over  in the old code thats messing with something.